# Export List With £ Symbol To CSV File - Unicode Error

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-requests, lxml

When I try to export a list to a csv file which contains a £ symbol, I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in
>   position 77: ordinal not in range(128)

I cannot reproduce the issue when passing symbols to a csv file in the same way. Therefore this leads me to believe that there is some sort of encoding error occurring.

I am scraping web pages using requests and then passing the html to lxml to find elements in a web page by xpath.

After I have the desired part of  a webpage by using this line of code to get i.e an item price:

```
itemPrice = productParser.xpath('//*[@id="prcIsum"]')
```

Usually I would have this returned:

```
[<Element span at 0x112f54db8>]
```

But I convert it to a readable form by altering the original code to:

```
itemPrice = productParser.xpath('string(//*[@id="prcIsum"])')
```

Therefore, I believe the string() is causing an issue, but I cannot find a way to get this to get the html into a readable from i.e (£5) and also be able to export to a csv file and actually be able to read it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 02/01/2018: 
The code below produces the same replicated error. 
Using Python 3.6.3, Mac Os High Sierra.

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html

exampleUrl = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/JVC-LT-32C675-32-HD-Ready-LED-Smart-TV-Built-in-DVD-Player-Freeview-HD-Black/122517378430"
productHtml = requests.get(exampleUrl,timeout=10)
productParser = html.fromstring(productHtml.text)

itemTitle = productParser.xpath('string(//*[@id="itemTitle"]/text())')
itemPrice = productParser.xpath('string(//*[@id="prcIsum"])')
numberSold= productParser.xpath('string(//span[contains(@class,"vi-qtyS")]//a)')

itemDetails = []
itemDetails.extend((itemTitle,itemPrice.strip(),numberSold.strip(" sold")))

with open("csc.csv","w") as file:
                   writer=csv.writer(file)
                   writer.writerow(itemDetails)
file.close()
```

Comment: what Python version you use ? do you use Windows ? did you try to display `£` on screen (Windows has problem to display `UTF-8` in console because it uses `CP125x` instead of `UTF-8` and then you can see `UnicodeEncodeError`). Did you try to encode string to `UTF-8` and write it in file ? Create minial working example with real url so we could see this page and test it.

Comment: @furas Please see updated code which you can replicate issue with.

Comment: your code works without problems on Linux Mint. Try `open("csc.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')`. Maybe it helps. In documentation for [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) you can see that it uses [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) to recognize encoding set in system. I get `UTF-8` when I run `import locale ; print(locale.getpreferredencoding())`

Comment: @furas That did it, so simple, cannot believe I overlooked that. Thank you for the help!